# Swift NSData String Conversion Based on Subset of NSData

Tags: arrays, string, swift, nsdata

### Situation

I'm working with binary data which has a string encoded in the middle.  What I'm trying to do is extract this string so that I can both "set" and "get" it.  I've come up with a methodology which seems a little funky (actually 3 options).  I've included a playground code which you can look at.

I'm wondering if there is a "better" way to work with this data than what I've come up. Better means more efficient or clearer code-wise.

To read the data I do the following -

1. make `var rawData` by converting the `NSMutableData` to `UnsafeMutablePoitner<UInt8>`
2. Create `var ptr : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` from `rawData.mutableBytes`
3. Create an array `bytes` of type `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>` from a combo of the 1st two variables
4. Create a new array consisting of just the bytes containing the string `bytes[19]` - `bytes[26]`
5. Extract this array into a string

Then to set the variable I have 3 methods but the one I think I would use is
1. Make a new string of 8 string
2. Create `[UInt8]` array of the characters of the string
3. Loop through each byte in the new array and set the value of the byte in the `bytes` array to the value in question

I'm assuming there is some way where I can be working directly with the "parent" byte array as opposed to making a sub-array to work with.  Playground code is below.  I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this and perhaps there is not one.

Thanks

#### Playground Code

```
import Cocoa
//import AppKit



///This is the raw data
var testBytes : [UInt8] = [0x14, 0x00, 0xAB, 0x45, 0x49, 0x1F, 0xEF, 0x15, 0xA8, 0x89, 0x78, 0x0F, 0x09, 0xA9, 0x07, 0xB0, 0x01, 0x20, 0x01, 0x4E, 0x38, 0x32, 0x35, 0x56, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x00]

///Convert into msgData
var msgData = NSMutableData(bytes: testBytes, length: testBytes.count)


// Store raw data into a byte array for messing with
var rawData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(data: msgData)
var ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(rawData.mutableBytes)
var bytes : UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: ptr, count: rawData.length)


// Extract Callsign from the data stream
var callsignArray : [UInt8] = [bytes[19], bytes[20], bytes[21], bytes[22], bytes[23], bytes[24], bytes[25], bytes[26]]
var callsignString = NSString(bytes: callsignArray, length: callsignArray.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let callsignString0 = callsignString!
println(callsignArray)
println("1. -- Initial Callsign [\(callsignString0)]")


//OPTION #1
// Edit Callsgin Array Directly (sketchy)
// And manually copy the bytes back into the base array
callsignArray[0] = 97
callsignArray[1] = 98
callsignArray[2] = 99
callsignArray[3] = 100

println(callsignArray)

// Write the new "bytes" back into the main array - there must be a better way
for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    bytes[19+i] = callsignArray[i]
}

let callsign1 = NSString(bytes: callsignArray, length: callsignArray.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

println("2. -- Modification of Bytes [\(callsign1)]")

//Option 3 - Go from String to Bytes

let callsign3 = "AABCDEF "
var buf = [UInt8](callsign3.utf8)

for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    bytes[19+i] = buf[i]
}
println(rawData)

callsignArray = [bytes[19], bytes[20], bytes[21], bytes[22], bytes[23], bytes[24], bytes[25], bytes[26]]
callsignString = NSString(bytes: callsignArray, length: callsignArray.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableData` has methods to extract and replace sub-ranges:

```
// Get: 
let subData = msgData.subdataWithRange(NSMakeRange(19, 8))
let string = NSString(data: subData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Set:
let newString = "AABCDEF "
let newData = newString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
msgData.replaceBytesInRange(NSMakeRange(19, 8), withBytes: newData.bytes, length: newData.length)
```

You can also operate on the `[UInt8]` array directly:

```
// Get:
let string = testBytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer($0.baseAddress + 19), length: 8, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}

// Set:
testBytes.replaceRange(19 ... 26, with: Array(newString.utf8))
```